# How to do a All() using Dynamic LINQ

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

as the same as here:
[How to do a Sum using Dynamic LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490080/how-to-do-a-sum-using-dynamic-linq)
I want to do a All() with a dynamic string...

My code:

```
allDataValid = consumptionModelListOld.All(x => x.F11ValueValid);
```

I want to write:

```
allDataValid = consumptionModelListOld.All("F11ValueValid");
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `All` "operator", and it would be quite difficult to create it... but you could:

```
allDataValid = !consumptionModelListOld.Where("!F11ValueValid").Any();
```

Note the use of `!` (twice, to negate the `F11ValueValid` and to negate the result of `Any()`).

Comment: @AlexH On my version of Dynamic Linq (I'm using [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)), there is no `.Any(string)` overload.